# undefined reference to `json11::Json::dump(std::string&) const' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, json, c++11, c++14

I using [json11](https://github.com/dropbox/json11) in my project

```
#include "crow_all.h"
#include "sqlOperations/sqlcpp_db_connection.cpp"
#include "date.h"
#include <json11.hpp>

int main() {
   crow::SimpleApp app;
   CROW_ROUTE(app,"/navOfFund")
            .methods("POST"_method)
    ([](const crow::request& req){
        auto x = crow::json::load(req.body);
        if (!x)
            return crow::response(400);
        auto name = x["fund_name"].s();
        std::ostringstream os;
        vector<double>nav =  select_from_fund_type(name);
        json11::Json json(nav);
        //std::cout << json.dump() << std::endl;
        return crow::response{json.dump()};
    });
    crow::logger::setLogLevel(crow::LogLevel::Debug);

    app.port(18080).multithreaded().run();
    return 0;
}
```

And i am compiling my project using below command

```
g++ -std=c++1y -L/usr/local/lib -I ../../date main.cpp -ljson11 -lsqlpp-mysql -lmysqlclient -lboost_system -lpthread
```

And the error is

```
/tmp/ccqQDgWQ.o: In function `json11::Json::dump() const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK6json114Json4dumpEv[_ZNK6json114Json4dumpEv]+0x2c): undefined reference to `json11::Json::dump(std::string&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not able to find the root cause of error.

But i don't know why, this works perfectly fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <json11.hpp>

int main()
{
   std::vector<double> test_vector { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 };
   json11::Json json(test_vector);

   std::cout << json.dump() << std::endl;
}
```

And compiling using

```
g++ -std=c++1y json_test.cpp -ljson11
```

Comment: Try `json11.cpp` instead of `-ljson11` in the command line. May be the library was built with incompatible flags.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin : Same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `void dump(std::string &out)` isn't defined in the `.hpp` file, see [here](https://github.com/dropbox/json11/blob/master/json11.hpp#L156).
Instead it is defined in the `.cpp` file, that is [here](https://github.com/dropbox/json11/blob/master/json11.cpp#L131).

You should rather do this:

```
g++ -std=c++1y -L/usr/local/lib -I ../../date main.cpp json11.cpp -lsqlpp-mysql -lmysqlclient -lboost_system -lpthread
```

Comment: Do i need to include `json11.cpp` instead of `json11.hpp`.

Comment: Inclusion of a cpp files is more a hack than usual practice when you programming with C++.

Comment: @Shravan40 Sorry, you **mustn't** include the `.cpp` file, you **must** compile it along with your `main.cpp` file **and** still include your `.hpp` file. In other terms, you are not compiling the `json11.cpp` file and the definition of the `dump` method is not available.

Comment: Funnily, this is exactly what I advised doing in my comment.

Comment: @skypjack That `json11.cpp` is what `-ljson11` built from, is it not? In other words, when `json11.cpp` is in the command line `-ljson11` is not used.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Unlikely. Anyway, you can post your answers as answers instead as of commenta if you are certain of them. That's how SO usually works. :-)

Comment: @skypjack I do not think you need both `json11.cpp` and `-ljson11`, you gave wrong advice.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Removed.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin If You are so upset for that to downvote the answer for no reason, post another answer and I'll remove this one. Next time, note also that this is the area for comments. Answers must be put in the big textarea you can see below.